# Notations from Rudin's book

Tags: real-analysis

This is taken from Rudin's book

Notations: If $x=(x_1,...,x_n) \in R^n$ and $y=(y_1,..,y_m)$ in $R^m$. and $(x_1,...,x_n,y_1,..,y_m) \in R^{n+m}$.

Every $A \in L(R^{n+m},R^n)$ can be split into two linear maps $A_x$ and $A_y$, defined by $A_x h = A(h,0), A_y k=A(0,k)$ for any $h \in R^n, k \in R^m$. Then $A_x \in L(R^n), A_y \in L(R^m,R^n)$ and $A(h,k)=A_xh +A_yk$.

My question is how do $A_x h = A(h,0), A_y k=A(0,k)$ and $A(h,k)=A_xh +A_yk$ work in terms of matrix operations? Specifically how do I check that those equations hold?

Comment: $A_x$ is $A$ with its last $m$ columns removed; $A_y$ is $A$ with its first $n$ columns removed.

Comment: I think $A_x$ is projection mapping along $X$- axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to treat $A$, $A_x$ and $A_y$ as matrices, then you should interpret all variables $0, h, k$, etc. as **column vectors**. For example, "$(h, k)$" actually means a $(n + m)$-dim column vector by stacking the $n$-dim column vector $h$ and the $m$-dim column vector $k$ together. Moreover, $A$ can be seen as the juxtaposition of $A_x$ and $A_y$: $A = \begin{bmatrix} A_x & A_y \end{bmatrix}$. With this, we have 
\begin{align}
A(h, k) = \begin{bmatrix}A_x & A_y\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} h \\ k\end{bmatrix} = A_xh + A_y k. \\
\end{align}

Setting $h = 0$ or $k = 0$ in the above equation, you can get other equalities verified.